Why does Google's Speech-to-Text API include all previously recognized words in each final result?
I'm using Google's Speech-to-Text API to transcribe streaming audio in my C++ application. Here’s my current implementation:
void reading() {
    google::cloud::speech::v1::StreamingRecognizeResponse response;
    while (recognition->Read(&response)) {
        for (const auto& result : response.results()) {
            if (result.is_final()) {
                const auto& data = result.alternatives(0);
                for (auto& word : data.words()) {
                    std::cout << "Word: " << word.word() << " : "
                              << word.speaker_label() << std::endl;
                }
                std::cout << "Final result: "
                          << result.alternatives(0).transcript() << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    recognition->WritesDone();
}

I’ve noticed that this implementation outputs all recognized words in each final result, including those from previous phrases. For example, if I say "Hi, how are you?" and then "How much is 2+2?", I get each phrase individually as expected, but the set of words includes all previously recognized words.
Question: Why does Google include all recognized words from previous phrases in each final result, instead of just the new words of the latest phrase? What is the practical sense of this?
Thank you!
